# Stop default scroll event by mousewheel under some condition. Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have div which has `onWheel`.

Browser treat onWheel as scroll by default.

However I want to stop  mouse browser behaivor in under condition.

However, for now I bumped into Unable to `preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation` error. some article says I should use `{ passive: false }` in addEventListener, but how can I do this in React?

```
handleWheel(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey){
        console.log("wheel is called, then want to stop scroll!!");
        e.stopPropagation(); //It doesn't stop default scroll behaivor.
        e.preventDefault();   //it shows the error Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.
    }
}

    <div onWheel={handleWheel} >
```

Answer (score 0):

please try like below:

```
document.getElementById("divScroll").addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  // your logic
}, {passive:false});

<div id="divScroll" >
```

Answer (score -1):

as the error message mentioned:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation

you have explicit to set the event listener to active by `{ passive: false }`

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Page = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;
    element?.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, { passive: false });
  }, []);

  const handleWheel = (event: any) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={ref} className="h-96 w-96 bg-red-300"></div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Page;
```